# Copying the shape of a polygon but paste it on a different location in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am labeling solar panels and often they have exactly the same shape. Is it possible to copy the shape of a polygon and paste it on another location in my shapefile?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the 'Advanced Digitizing Toolbar' under View > Toolbars.

Select the polygon you want to copy, then use the 'Copy and Move Feature(s)' button which is hidden in a drop down behind the regular 'Move Feature(s)' tool:

[image]